# Nginx from source, return 403 Forbidden

Tags: permissions, nginx

I have installed nginx with source code on Ubuntu 19.10 installed on virtual machine.
iptables disabled.
selinux disabled.
firewalld disabled.
I start the server this way:

```
./root/nginx-1.16.1/objs/nginx
```

The server is running smoothly.
But if I try to reach on the ip address I get:

```
 wget 127.0.0.1:443
--2019-10-30 07:41:27--  http://127.0.0.1:443/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2019-10-30 07:41:27 ERROR 400: Bad Request.

wget 192.168.136.133:443
--2019-10-30 07:42:00--  http://192.168.136.133:443/
Connecting to 192.168.136.133:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2019-10-30 07:42:00 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

In **error.log** I see:

```
2019/10/30 07:34:59 [error] 1325#0: *1 "/root/nginx-1.16.1/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.136.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "192.168.136.133"
2019/10/30 07:41:18 [error] 1325#0: *2 "/root/nginx-1.16.1/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Do you have any ideas about what the problem might be?

For information:
**nginx.conf**:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log debug;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
     error_log  logs/error.log debug;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {

    ########################################################
    ########################################################
        # Enable QUIC and HTTP/3.
        listen 443 quic reuseport;

        # Enable HTTP/2 (optional).
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate      cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

        # Enable all TLS versions (TLSv1.3 is required for QUIC).
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        # Add Alt-Svc header to negotiate HTTP/3.
        add_header alt-svc 'h3-23=":443"; ma=86400';
    ########################################################
    ########################################################


        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}



    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

**permission:**

```
ll
total 812
drwxr-xr-x 15   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 20:49 ./
drwx------ 14 root   root   4096 Oct 30 09:49 ../
drwxr-xr-x  6   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 18:35 auto/
-rw-r--r--  1   1001 1001 296463 Aug 13 14:51 CHANGES
-rw-r--r--  1   1001 1001 452171 Aug 13 14:51 CHANGES.ru
drwx------  2 nobody root   4096 Oct 29 20:49 client_body_temp/
drwxr-xr-x  2   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 20:49 conf/
-rwxr-xr-x  1   1001 1001   2502 Aug 13 14:51 configure*
drwxr-xr-x  4   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 18:32 contrib/
drwx------  2 nobody root   4096 Oct 29 20:49 fastcgi_temp/
drwxrwxrwx  2   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 18:32 html/
-rw-r--r--  1   1001 1001   1397 Aug 13 14:51 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Oct 30 09:47 logs/
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    384 Oct 29 18:37 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x  2   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 18:32 man/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Oct 29 19:00 objs/
drwx------  2 nobody root   4096 Oct 29 20:49 proxy_temp/
-rw-r--r--  1   1001 1001     49 Aug 13 14:51 README
drwx------  2 nobody root   4096 Oct 29 20:49 scgi_temp/
drwxr-xr-x  9   1001 1001   4096 Oct 29 18:32 src/
drwx------  2 nobody root   4096 Oct 29 20:49 uwsgi_temp/
```

**Do you have any ideas about what the problem might be?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typically happens when the user/group running the `nginx` worker process(es) (on a regular installation it's `www-data`) does not have permission to access/read the file used to serve the response. This could be the case that the user does not have sufficient permission to traverse the directories or could be that they simply don't have the read permission on the file.

As you're starting the `nginx` server manually, you need to make sure the invoking user (the user that runs `./root/nginx-1.16.1/objs/nginx`) actually has permission to read `/root/nginx-1.16.1/html/index.html`. You can easily check that from terminal by running `ls` as that user:

```
ls /root/nginx-1.16.1/html/index.html
```

Then it's a permission fixing issue mainly.

Also, whenever possible, please stick to the official packages from Ubuntu unless of course you intentionally want to compile the binaries yourself maybe to enable a compile time option that is missing in the official release. If that's the case, you can also open a request on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) against that package and discuss with the maintainers about enabling the option, maybe they can add that option afterwards after discussing.

Comment: as a super user
I'll read the file,

how else can I fix it, how else can I fix it? I have edit with the permission in directory. Yes i run with source code for implement http3.

Comment: @giuseppeDiPalma I can see UID `1001` owning the file, maybe you have removed the user as `ls` showing UID instead of username. Run the server as `root` and then check.

Comment: i run server with sudo and same problems. ||sudo ./nginx||

Comment: ll /root/nginx-1.16.1/html/index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 612 Aug 13 14:51 /root/nginx-1.16.1/html/index.html

Comment: @giuseppeDiPalma Set `error_log  logs/error.log debug;` and check out the log.

Comment: i see same error. I have edit the question with code of new nginx.conf

Comment: @giuseppeDiPalma Can you set `user root;` in the conf and then run the server to check?

Comment: where i set it? `location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }` with `/root/nginx-1.16.1/html`

Comment: @giuseppeDiPalma At the start of your `nginx.conf`, see there's a `user` directive.

Comment: Yes. Now it run.

Comment: @giuseppeDiPalma *It works* does not mean that is an optimum way. You really should not run the workers as `root`, look at using some other user and setting permissions for that user specifically.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

At the beginning of the file *conf/nginx.conf*

i set it:

```
user  root;
```

Comment: please don't use root here, you don't want nginx EVER running as root - it's in most cases something everyone can interact with and you're giving it way too many permissions